# Multi threading queries Oracle / java 7

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm having performance issue trying to query large table, with multiple threads.
I'm using Oracle, Spring 2 and java 7.

I use a PoolDataSource (driver oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource) with as many connections as the number of thread to analyse a single table.
I made sure by logging `poolDataSource.getStatistics()` that I have enough available connections at any time.

Here is the code :

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nbThreads);
List<Foo> foo = new ArrayList<>();

List<Callable<List<Foo>>> callables = new ArrayList<>();

int offset = 1;

while(offSetMaxReached) {
    callables.add(new Callable<List<Foo>> {
        @Override
        public List<Foo> call() throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
            return dao.doTheJob(...);
        }
    });
    offset += 10000;
}

for(Future<List<Foo>> fooFuture : executorService.invokeAll(callables)) {
    geometrieIncorrectes.addAll(fooFuture.get());
}

executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

In the dao, I use a connection from the PoolDataSource, and Spring JdbcTemplate.query(query, PreparedStatementSetter, RowCallBackHandler).
The `doTheJob` method do the exact same thing for every query results.

My queries look like : `SELECT A, B, C FROM MY.BIGTABLE OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY`

So, to sum up, I have n threads called by a FixThreadPool, each thread deal with the exact same amount of data and do the exact same things.
But each thread completion is longer than the last one !

Example :
4 threads launched at the same time, but the first row of each resultSet (ie in the RowCallBackHandlers) is processed at :

- thread 1 : 1.5s
- thread 2 : 9s
- thread 3 : 18s
- thread 4 : 35s

and so on...

What can be the cause of such behavior ?

Edit :

The main cause of the problem was within the processed table itself.
Using `OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY`, Oracle needs to run through all the lines, starting by one.

So accessing offset 10 is faster than accessing offset 10000000 !

I was able to get good response time with temporary tables, and good indexes.

Comment: If you just need to pull all data from the table, you might be better off simply running a single query without any threading or paging and setting the [JDBC fetch size](http://makejavafaster.blogspot.com/2015/06/jdbc-fetch-size-performance.html) sufficiently large (default is only 10 rows/result set). Maybe try that first?

Comment: You need to trace it from the database side. Ask your DBA to find and trace this query (`alter system set events 'sql_trace[sql: sql_id_of_your_query] level=12';`)